# Rails MIME::Types.type_for return an array of strings or of objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mime-types

From various questions on SO, it seems like it returns strings

```
MIME::Types.type_for("my_video.mp4").to_s
 => "[application/mp4, audio/mp4, video/mp4, video/vnd.objectvideo]"
```

but in my Rails console, it returns (Rails 4.0.5)

```
"[#<MIME::Type:0x00000001da0470 @content_type=\"application/mp4\", @raw_media_type=\"application\", @raw_sub_type=\"mp4\", @simplified=\"application/mp4\", @media_type=\"application\", @sub_type=\"mp4\", @extensions=[\"mp4\", \"mpg4\"] ...
```

Did the `to_s` method change? This is an issue because I need to override the content type of a paperclip upload based on the file name. Specifically, pdf files have been mistakenly thought of as `text/html`.